# Command with arguments in pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, arguments, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

pyTelegramBotAPI version - 3.0.1

Version of python:
2.7/3.6.1

I want to create a command with arguments, example:

```
/activate 1
/run programm
```

How to do it?

Comment: @NoamHacker, I thought of dividing the resulting line, but I do not know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution:

```
def extract_arg(arg):
    return arg.split()[1:]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['yourCommand'])
def yourCommand(message):
    status = extract_arg(message.text)
```

> /yourCommand 1

```
status = ['1']
```

> /yourCommand ff

```
status = ['ff']
```